# How to create JSON for JAXBElement?

Tags: java, json, jersey, jaxbelement

BACKGROUNG

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    ...//accessors
}


@Path("mypath")
 public class PersonResource{
   @POST
   @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response addPerson(JAXBElement<Person> jaxbPerson) {
      Person person = jaxbPerson.getValue();
       ...//logic etc.
   }     
}
```

`PersonResource. addPerson` will accept `{"firstName":"Alfred","lastName":"Bell"}` but not `{"person":{"firstName":"Alfred","lastName":"Bell"}}`.

Because of that I have the following problem.

PROBLEM:

GIVEN

```
@XmlRootElement
public class car {
    private String maker;
    private String model;

   private AirBag airbag;
   private List<Tire> tires;

   @XmlElementWrapper(name = "tires")
   @XmlElement(name = "tire")
   public Set<Tire> get Tires() {
       return this.tires;
   }
    ...// more accessors
}


@Path("add-car")
 public class CarResource{
   @POST
   @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response addPerson(JAXBElement<Car> jaxbCar) {
       Car car = jaxbCar.getValue();
       ...//logic etc.
   }     
}
```

How do I format the JSON so that `JAXBElement<Car> jaxbCar` recognizes it? The car must have four tires and an airbag.

DETAILS:

I am using Jersey (Java REST-API).

Comment: Just a small comment: I find GSON to be a MUCH superior library

Answer (score 0):

Try to send your object as argument to the addPerson() method

```
public Person  addPerson(Person person){

    Person fme = new Person ();
        ...
}
```

And don't forget the add `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` right before `@XmlrootElement`

Comment: What if the client is a website where will they get the `Person` object from?

Comment: Normaly when you want to post data, you need a form on your website pages that allow sending the person object in JSON file,all what you have to do is annotating you `addPerson()` method with `@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})`